# Maximum number of nodes that can be in a tree of height K?

Tags: java, tree, nodes

So, I'm looking at the maximum number of nodes that can be in a tree of height 8.

I believe the correct formula for this is 2^(k+1) - 1. Therefore 2^8+1 - 1 = 511.
I am confused because I see a lot of different answers and material online.

Can anyone confirm If I'm correct/incorrect and shed some light
Thanks in advance

Comment: To verify your answer, simply draw out trees of increasing height on a piece of paper starting from `K = 1`; this way, you'll be able to verify your formula quickly.

Comment: Did you mean `2^(k+1) - 1`?

Comment: ^ Yes I did I changed it

Comment: Answer depends on how many branches a node can handle. [Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) don't have to be [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), i.e. nodes with 2 branches. They can have more.

Comment: @Andreas I think in this instance a node can handle two branches. Could you explain further what you mean?

Comment: Typically, trees are binary, where a node has a single value, and you follow left branch or right branch, depending on search value relative to the node value. However, a node could have multiple branch values, e.g. a node could have values `4, 9, 13`, with 4 branches leaving the node. The number of branches may not even be constant in a single tree. This is common if nodes are stored on disk, where you might want a node to fill a disk sector, to reduce the number of node lookups (disk reads) to navigate the tree. Most RDBMS indexes are built that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you are talking about a binary tree, so the answer is easy. 2^k-1, so in your case 2^8-1 = 255.

Take a tree of height k, if you add a new level you can duplicate the number of nodes by adding two nodes in each leaf. If you take the tree of height 1, it has 1 node, 2^1-1; height 2, 2^2-1=3…

Comment: So therefore my answer for K=8 should be 2^8 - 1 = 255?

Comment: Thanks, could this formula be used also to find the minimum height of a tree with e.g. 85 nodes. As the minimum height would mean each node has two branches. Would it work to simply to re-arrange 2^(k) - 1 = 85 and then using natural log to isolate K?

Comment: @MD9 Yes technically, you could use `log2(n + 1)`, rounding up, i.e. for `n = 85` you get `ceil(log2(86)) = 7`. However, it would be faster to use bit logic by calling [`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-int-). As javadoc shows: `ceil(log2(x)) = 32 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x - 1)`, so for you that would be `32 - numberOfLeadingZeros(n + 1 - 1) = 32 - numberOfLeadingZeros(n)`.

Comment: @MD9 Yes, with the formula you can do: log2(85+1) = 6,4 ≈ 7. It is cause you are using the formula, with height 6 you can take 2^6-1 = 63, and with 7, 2^7 -1 = 127. So as the formula is 2^k -1 = nodes, you could do log2(nodes+1) = K

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. The max number  of nodes in a tree with height h (start as height of leaf node is 0)
= (2^(h+1)) -1
= (2^(8+1)) - 1 = (2^9) -1 =511

The height of a node in a binary tree is the largest number of edges in a path from a leaf node to a target node.

Then for a tree with height 1, the maximum number of nodes is 3( one root node and 2 children=1+2). Same result from (2^(h+1)) -1 = (2^2)-1=3

Then for a tree with height 2, the maximum number of nodes is 7( one root node and 2 children and then 2 children of each =1+2+4). Same result from (2^(h+1)) -1 = (2^3)-1=7

Then for a tree with height 3, the maximum number of nodes is 15( one root node and 2 children and there 2 children for each again 2 children for each = 1+2+4+8). Same result from (2^(h+1)) -1 = (2^4)-1=15

This is my first answer on stackoverflow, Upvote to cheers .

You can also check this geeksforgeeks link for more understanding

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/relationship-number-nodes-height-binary-tree/